# Which JDK to compile commons-dbcp-1.2.2 ? (problems with JDK5/6/7)

Tags: java-6, java-7, apache-commons-dbcp, java-5

When I try to compile [commons-dbcp-1.2.2](http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/dbcp/source/commons-dbcp-1.2.2-src.tar.gz) with JDK6/7 I get this error:

> org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource is not abstract and does not override abstract method isWrapperFor(java.lang.Class) in java.sql.Wrapper

This is because commons-dbcp-1.2.2 was written before JDK6, at a time where `java.sql.Wrapper` did not have an `isWrapperFor` method.

So I installed JDK5, but I get such messages (probably because of all the Java7-compiled JARs):

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to compile commons-dbcp-1.2.2 and here is how I did:

1. Download revision 558600 (because someone wrote the right patch for it. It is pretty much 1.2.2 with a few fixes)

   ```
   svn checkout -r 558600 http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/dbcp/trunk commons-dbcp
   ```
2. Download [this patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12362389/patch.txt) ([explanation of the patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DBCP-191)) and patch:

   ```
   wget https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12362389/patch.txt
   patch -p0 <patch.txt
   ```

Copy `build.properties.sample` to `build.properties`, download the jars described in the file, and change to appropriate paths.

Build with OpenJDK 7.